# Convert csv file to xlsx in android java [android 6]

Tags: java, android, csv, xlsx, aspose-cells

I am creating a csv file by taking data from SQLite table. I want to convert the csv file to xlsx format for it to be shared by bluetooth. I am limited to android 6.

I have tried:

1. Apache POI (Min SDK Android 8)
2. GroupDocs (Heap Memory Runs out)
3. Aspose

The 3rd one seems to work without android 6 but it gives error.

Here are the code snippets:

Generate Excel:

```
 genrateExcel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/";

            LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(FileFormatType.CSV);

            Workbook workbook = null;
            try {
                workbook = new Workbook(file + "SensorData.csv", loadOptions);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                workbook.save(file + "CSVtoExcel.xlsx" , SaveFormat.XLSX);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

My CSV file is generated and is being saved in the Downloads Folder and is visible to user.

[image: Page Where we export to CSV and Convert to XLSX]

I am getting an error on the line:

```
 workbook = new Workbook(file + "SensorData.csv", loadOptions);
```

Here is the link to the logcat file:
[Logcat Link](https://batbin.me/overvault)

It says some class is missing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/SystemColor;
```

and this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.SystemColor"
```

I have searched whole internet for the conversion and didn't find any suitable to my needs.My last option is using Aspose but it shows some errors which also cannot be found upon Googling. Thanks in advance to all the people who will be helping.

Comment: Although Android supports the Java language, it doesn't have the full runtime environment of actual Java, which means that libraries developed for the JVM don't necessarily work on Android, because Android might miss classes.

Comment: You may try [fastexcel](https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel).

Comment: Please try using Aspose.Cells for Android via Java (https://products.aspose.com/cells/android-java/) API (latest version). Let us know if you find any issue.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.